# appium v1.7.2, When I enter text in secure password field then only single character is entered instead full string in java

Tags: java, appium

appium v1.7.2
Technology - Java

Below Method is used -

```
public void setLoginPassword(String loginPswd) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
        WebElement a = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(loginPassword));
        loginPassword.sendKeys(loginPswd);      

    }
```

Comment: Which OS version you are using and what is the device name, Also is it failing for all values or only for password field ?

Comment: I have tried for both android 6.0 and android 7.1.1. For both of them the same problem occurs. Checked for emulator and real device also.

Comment: It is failing only for Password field.

Comment: Change the element id and value and try this code for passsword field driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfq').setAttribute('value','Selenium Web Driver')");

Comment: driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfq').setAttribute('value','Selenium Web Driver')"); Which Driver I have to import? Because in case of AppiumDriver, error is generated as Method is not implemented. I am writing this:                                 ((AppiumDriver) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('inputPassword').setAttribute('value','pass12123')");

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with email field on Google Sign In page.

This code helped me that time (updated for appium-java-client 6.1.0):

```
    WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(<locator>);
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.longPress(LongPressOptions.longPressOptions()
            .withElement(ElementOption.element(passwordField)))
            .release()
            .perform();
    driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(<passwordValue>);
```

If that won't help try to play with Android keyboard, e.g solution mentioned here 
https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/916#issuecomment-392558236